# SQL SERVER CONSULTA

Tags: sql-server

Quiero hacer una consulta en SQL SERVER que me muestre los primeros tres registros de la tabla por Id_Operacion. En dicha tabla hay otros Id_Operacion. Yo quiero obtener los primeros tres de cada Id_Operacion.

La tabla se llama Cuadropagos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando dices 'los tres primeros' te refieres a los 3 con la Fecha2Pago más baja/alta? el periodo más pequeño/grande? los intereses más altos/bajos? ...

Comment: LOS 3 PRIMEROS CON LA FECHA MAS ALTA, PERO POR Id_Operacion

Comment: A propósito, revisando tu historial veo que preguntás mucho pero nunca marcás las respuestas como correctas. Va a llegar un punto en que nadie va a querer ayudarte, ponete las pilas.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (select row_number() over (partition by id_operacion order by fecha2pago desc) r,
      *
      from CUADROPAGOS) q
where r <= 3
order by id_operacion, fecha2pago desc
```

Comment: hey muchas gracias me ayudaste bastante, ahora la estoy acoplando a otras necesidades, y yo siempre marco como respuestas

Comment: @Quesada me refiero a aceptar la respuesta marcando la tilde de visto bueno. Leé → https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer